# jQuery to validate only leading ZERO price numeric string

Tags: jquery, price

I would like to validate a price field in html form that a leading ZERO like 0350, 024879, etc. are not allowed and jQuery will issue a warning while typing. Here is jQuery should do when typing a leading ZERO number into the price field:

a) a popup warning message like 'ZERO leading number not allowed. Please correct it!'

b) Clear off or remove that invalid price from the price field with/without a delay

c) What is the correct Regex for validating just ZERO leading numeric string? for example, typing 09, 038, etc. is not accepted. But typing 0u, 0& (with non numeric characters) is accepted.

Here is my codes:

HTML:

```
    <input type="text" id="price" name="price">
```

jQuery:

```
    jQuery('#price').on("keyup", function() {
      var price = $(this).val();
      var partern = /^(?:[1-9][0-9]*|0)$/;
      var valid = partern.test(price);

      if (!valid) {
        alert('Invalid price. Please input numerical characters');
        setTimeout(function (e) {
            $this.val(null);
        },500);
      }
    });
```

Any advice would be very appreciated.

Comment: *"without a delay"* - why did you put `setTimeout`? also, you missed braces on `$this.val(null)` it should be `$(this).val(null)`.

Comment: I would strongly discourage modifying the field while typing and would recommend instead to use other means to inform the user of bad input. I would also discourage use of blocking operations such as `alert` as they interrupt workflow.

Comment: A word of caution... if you insist on modifying the field, please understand that "keyup" is one way of entering data.  For example, copying and pasting a value in the field would bypass a "keyup" event.

Comment: The question should be revised with better constraints on the number requirement.  For example, must the number be an `integer` or is a `float` also allowed?  If so, a leading zero may be valid input for a decimal, e.g. `$0.25`.

Comment: Hi, I try the one you advised with braces; it does not work for a similar removing; but this one $this.val(null) without braces work. Not sure what is the correct way? Cheers

Comment: @daro2013 `this` keyword is contextual and changes meaning inside the `setTimeout` function.  If you remove the `setTimeout`, `$(this).val` will work.  Alternately, you may set `$(this)` to a variable (e.g. `var x = $(this)`) to be used later.

Comment: Hi tresf
The reason 0u, 0& (0 + non numeric characters) are accepted is because I have another jQuery function which issues instant warning message and automatically clear that non numerical character immediately keeping only numerical ones. So, if that is the case 0u,  0& is entered, another jquery function will deal with it. I just want the above function to deal with 07, 082, etc. Cheers

Comment: @daro2013 I've made several comments in regards to problems with the question.  Assuming you ignore them, `if (price.trim().indexOf("0") === 0) { /* nasty stuff */ }` but this doesn't answer all bullet points, mostly because the example already works as described.  Your regex example also works OK in my testing, once the `setTimeout` is removed, per @bagus-tesa's recommendation.

Comment: HI tresf
Yes, it is working. I ll give full update when another Regex issue is resolved. What regex should be for my case above? Cheers

Comment: but this $this.val(null); will work inside double setTimeout(); I mean inside the second setTimeout() inside the first one. Thanks

Comment: FIXED. I just move another jQuery function to the above function. When typing 0&, 0y, etc. that will be dealt by another function which issues instant warning; the above function wont have a chance to deal with it. I have learned a lots over the last week. May thanks for this great community.

Comment: `$(this)` inside your event listener **!=** `$(this)` inside the timeout callback - [reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3127429/how-does-the-this-keyword-work-and-when-should-it-be-used)

Answer (score 0):

ANOTHER FIXED:
I have issue with using both this or (this) in jQuery on my Wordpress; they dont work with setTimeout(), and cannot generalise this issue for other Wordpres theme. But I tested this one:

```
    setTimeout(function (e) {
    //  $this.val(null);      // $this works with setTimeout inside another setTimeout
      jQuery('#price').val('');   // Reset or clear off url input field after a warning
    },500);
```

jQuery('#price').val(''); does work with setTimeout() function. Here are full codes with a time delay:

```
    HTML:
    <input type="text" id="price" name="price"> 

    jQuery:
    jQuery('#price').on("keyup", function() {
      var price = $(this).val();
      var partern = /^(?:[1-9][0-9]*|0)$/;
      var valid = partern.test(price);

      if (!valid) {
        alert('Invalid price. Please input numerical characters');
        setTimeout(function (e) {
            jQuery('#price').val('');    // does not work with setTimeout()
        },500);
      }
    });
```

Many thanks

Answer (score -1):

FIXED:
Here is my codes:

```
    HTML:
    <input type="text" id="price" name="price"> 

    jQuery:
    jQuery('#price').on("keyup", function() {
      var price = $(this).val();
      var partern = /^(?:[1-9][0-9]*|0)$/;
      var valid = partern.test(price);

      if (!valid) {
        alert('Invalid price. Please input numerical characters');
       // setTimeout(function (e) {
            ($this).val(null);    // does not work with setTimeout()
       // },500);
      }
    });
```

Many thanks.

Comment: It does work with setTimeout, you are just assuming that `this` inside the event handler is the same `this` inside the callback, which it's not

Comment: No, this and (this) do not work with setTimeout which I have tried before two developers above advised.

Comment: [demo](https://jsfiddle.net/w89tmkv1/) - Please go read the [reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3127429/how-does-the-this-keyword-work-and-when-should-it-be-used) I've linked in the comment section

Comment: Hi thanks. You use a diffent input.val(null);  as event handler. What if there are more input in a form? thanks

Comment: I've adjusted the [demo](https://jsfiddle.net/fLv8s4gn/) - The problem is just the fact that (the second) `this` doesn't point to the input, you can verify this by doing `console.log(this)` in the callback, therefore you need to save a reference to the correct input - `const input = $(this);` - which will be accessible in the callback

Comment: You could indeed use `$('#price').val('')` like you did in the second answer, but seeing your comment (*What if there are more input in a form?*), you've already realized it's not the best solution because you would need to create a different listener for each input